# How to display my location on Google Maps Nativescript

Tags: google-maps, maps, nativescript

I'm using this [plugin](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-google-maps-sdk#ui-settings) in my project.

I want to show my location in map. In document I read in

```
**UI Settings**
myLocationButtonEnabled boolean - Whether the my-location button is enabled/disabled
```

How to apply this in code?

I try also to write this code:

```
  onMapReady(event) {
    this.mapView = event.object;
          var marker = new Marker();
          marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(-33.86, 151.20);
          marker.userData = { index: 1 };
          this.mapView.addMarker(marker);
          this.mapView.myLocationEnabled= true;   
  }
```

This `this.mapView.myLocationEnabled= true;` doesn't function.

Can you suggest me any idea how to display my location please?

Answer (score 0):

It's already described in the [ReadMe file](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk#ui-settings),

> You can adjust the Map UI settings after mapReady by changing the below properties on **mapView.settings**
>
> *myLocationButtonEnabled  boolean - Whether the my-location button is
> enabled/disabled*

The code should be,

```
this.mapView.settings.myLocationButtonEnabled = true;
```

Make sure you acquire location permissions before enabling the location button as showcased in the [demo app](https://github.com/dapriett/nativescript-google-maps-sdk/blob/master/demo/app/main-page.js#L132).

Comment: In my application, setting the properties did not work on Android (plugin @nativescript/google-maps) and threw an error. I used the following code
`const casted: any = event.map;
const uiSettings = casted.native.getUiSettings();
uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
casted.native.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

Comment: The plugin is not updated in a long time. Please post the details of your NS and plugin version, error details.

Comment: @Manjo The last commit to the plugin @nativescript/google-maps was only 29 days ago. If setting the property directly then the error message is (NS v8.2.2, Android): `TypeError: Cannot set property myLocationButtonEnabled of [object Object] which has only a getter`.

Comment: Then the plugin you are using is different from what's discussed in this thread. Your plugin doesn't support setting location button enabled attribute on Android, you have to conditionally use it for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

```
onMapReady(event) {
  this.mapView.gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
}
```

I hope you are missing gMap