# ERROR Error: java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, nativescript

I want to use google maps in my project. For this:

In first I install and configuration plugin `>> tns plugin add nativescript-google-maps-sdk` This plugin works good for me.

In second I want to display in google maps also and my current location, for this I install `>> tns plugin add nativescript-geolocation`

In `AndroidMainfest.xml` add

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
<supports-screens />
<uses-sdk />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<application>
.......
</application>
</manifest>
```

and in ts component

```
onMapReady(event) {
    this.mapView = event.object;
    this.ws.mobile_base_pharmacyGetAll().subscribe(
        items => {
            console.log(items)
            this.items = items;
            if (items !== undefined || items !== undefined) {
                for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {            
                    var marker = new Marker();
                    marker.position = Position.positionFromLatLng(this.items[i].latitude, this.items[i].longitude);
                    marker.title = this.items[i].name;
                    marker.snippet = this.items[i].address1;
                    marker.userData = { index: 1 };
                    this.mapView.addMarker(marker);   
                    this.mapView.myLocationEnabled = true;   
               }
            }
        },
        err => console.error('err', err),
        () => console.log('error')
    );
}
```

This code in Android 5.1.1 works very well. In Android version 7 and more does not work. Error:

> JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires
>   permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION JS:
>   com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bg.c(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785050@17.7.85
>   (040406-253824076):545) JS:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.m.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785050@17.7.85
>   (040406-253824076):361) JS:
>   hp.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17785050@17.7.85
>   (040406-253824076):4) JS:
>   android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499) JS:
>   com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.transactAndReadExceptionReturnVoid(Unknown
>   Source) JS:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown
>   Source) JS:
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(Unknown
>   Source) JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method) JS: 
>   com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083) JS:
>   com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)

Can you suggest me any idea please, what is a problem and how to solution? I can't find any solution in google.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

I change it, but nothing change, error exist.

[image]

Comment: did you added permissions in your manifest

Comment: Yes, I update my post. Thnx

Comment: did you put code for runtime permissions as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display my location on Google Maps Nativescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56849721/how-to-display-my-location-on-google-maps-nativescript)

Comment: Do not get confused between native projects & NativeScript, you are not suppose to edit anything with platforms folder as it's auto generated by {N} CLI. I'm marking this as duplicate as the answer is already covered in my answer for your previous post. The demo app clearly show cases how you should acquire the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Starting Android 6.0, the user must approve permissions at runtime. Here you can find the official [Google Developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

A useful reactive library for handling runtime permissions is: https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with Android 6.0 (API level 23), users can revoke permissions from any app at any time, even if the app targets a lower API level.

Add this code in your MainActivity.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
} else {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
      Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION }, 
      TAG_CODE_PERMISSION_LOCATION);
}
```

See details https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Please can you specify, in which file I add this code?

Comment: you can add your MainActivity in onCreate Method

Comment: Please can you see my Update in post ?